# Modal window blocking lightning edit record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-app-builder

I have a screen guided flow which I am calling through lightning component .
Now that lightning component I have added to a lightning record page to be visible on a particular status value of case record .
Its perfectly working on record .

But when I am trying to edit the lightning record page the modal window is  blocking everything and not allowing anything to edit . Everytime I have to disable  the component and then edit and then again enable it .

Any idea how can I resolve it .

My component code

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name ="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <aura:attribute name="displayModal" type="Boolean" default="true"  />
   
 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.displayModal}">
      
   <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aura:id="myModal"> 
      
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"  class="slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-border-inverse" variant="brand"  size="large"   onclick="{!c.closeFlowModal}"/>
               
       <div class="slds-modal__container">
           <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"  class="slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-border-inverse" variant="brand"  size="large"   onclick="{!c.closeFlowModal}"/>
                           
       <header class="slds-modal__header">
      <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"  class="slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-border-inverse" variant="brand"  size="large"   onclick="{!c.closeFlowModal}"/>
                   

        </header>
         <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
              
         
               <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.closeModalOnFinish}" /> 
         
</div>
            </div>
           </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" aura:id="myModal-Back"></div>
      
       
      </aura:if> 

</aura:component>
```

And here is the controller code

```
({  doInit:function(component,event,helper)
  {
     
     console.log("here");
     
       var flow = component.find("flowData");
       
        var inputVariables = [
 

         { name : "recordId", type : "String", value: component.get("v.recordId") }
 

          ];
        flow.startFlow('Case_Flow',inputVariables);
    
  },
   
  closeFlowModal: function(component, event, helper) {
     
      
      var modal = component.find("myModal");
    var modalBackdrop = component.find("myModal-Back");

  
   
      component.set("v.displayModal", false);
    
     
   },
  
  closeModalOnFinish : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED") {
         
            component.set("v.displayModal", false);
        }}
            
  })
```

Comment: It is hard to answer on your question without looking at your code. You should provide a code snippet of the component .

Comment: Hi @VitaliiDehnerys thanks for replying ,adding the code